# Why is set a sheaf category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am curious why set is a sheaf category. Where does the opposite category come into need? Is it because we consider first the case where the sheaf takes values in the category of sets.

Comment: please what are the definitions sheaf and sheaf category that you are using here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category of sets is the category of sheaves on the one-point category in which only the nonempty sieve is covering. The contravariance condition is irrelevant here, since the one-point category is self-dual.